# PyTorch Equvivlent of keras Model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, yolo

I am learning PyTorch and I am trying to convert a yolov3 model (from keras) to PyTorch. Now problem I am facing is that there is a code snippet which I am finding difficult to convert it to PyTorch. That is

```py
def yolo_body(inputs, num_anchors, num_classes):
    """Create YOLO_V3 model CNN body in Keras."""
    darknet = Model(inputs, darknet_body(inputs))    
    x, y1 = make_last_layers(darknet.output, 512, num_anchors*(num_classes+5))
    x = compose(
            DarknetConv2D_BN_Leaky(256, (1,1)),
            UpSampling2D(2))(x)
    x = Concatenate()([x,darknet.layers[152].output])
    #---- further code
```

Now I want to know what is the pytorch equvivlent of `Model` from Keras. My `darknet_body` implementation is

```py
class yolov3:
    ----
    ----
    def darknet_body(self, x):
        """Darknent body having 52 Convolution2D layers"""
        x = self.DarknetConv2D_BN_Leaky(32, (3, 3))(x)
        x = self.resblock_body(x, 64, 1)
        x = self.resblock_body(x, 128, 2)
        x = self.resblock_body(x, 256, 8)
        x = self.resblock_body(x, 512, 8)
        x = self.resblock_body(x, 1024, 4)
        return x
```

And `resblock_body` implementation is.

```py
class yolov3:
    ----
    ----
    def resblock_body(self, x, num_filters, num_blocks):
        """A series of resblocks starting with a downsampling Convolution2D"""
        # Darknet uses left and top padding instead of 'same' mode
        x = torch.nn.ZeroPad2d(((1, 0), (1, 0)))(x)
        x = self.DarknetConv2D_BN_Leaky(num_filters, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)
        for i in range(num_blocks):
            y = compose(
                self.DarknetConv2D_BN_Leaky(num_filters // 2, (1, 1)),
                self.DarknetConv2D_BN_Leaky(num_filters, (3, 3)),
            )(x)
            x = torch.add(x, y)
        return x
```

I also want to know how can I get the layer number like `darknet.layers[152]` as done in `yolo_body`.

Thanks.